# Does $\frac{\partial \dot{r}}{\partial \dot{q}}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial q}?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics, partial-derivative

Would it considered abuse of notation to say something in the grounds of
$$\frac{\partial \dot{r_i}}{\partial \dot{q_j}}=\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}?$$

It is supposed to follow from
$$\dot{r_i}=\sum\limits_{k}\frac{\partial r_j}{\partial q_k}\dot{q_k}+\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial t}.$$

But I can't see it.

Comment: It's potentially incorrect. What are $r$, $\dot r$, $q$, and $\dot q$?

Comment: @Valentina You want to check that this equality is true in some context or want to know if this is just a usual notation? What is the domain of definition of their functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the dot stands for time derivative.

The answer is that *it depends*.

Assume first that $r_i$ is a function of time and the quantities $q_j$ alone. In that case we get from the chain rule that
$$
\dot r_i=\frac{dr_i}{dt}=\sum_j\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}\dot q_j+\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial t}.
$$
From this we see that $\dot r_i$ is a linear function in the quantities $\dot q_j$. The claim follows from this, because it is no different from saying that for any "constants" (=not depending on the $x_i$:s) $a_j$ we have
$$
\frac{\partial(\sum_j a_jx_j)}{\partial x_i}=a_i.
$$

On the other hand, if the time derivatives $\dot q_j$ appear explicitly in the functions $r_i$, then this is false. For example, if
$$
r=r(q,\dot q)=q\dot q,
$$
then
$$
\dot r=\frac{dr}{dt}=(\dot q)^2+q \ddot q.
$$
So in this case
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial q}=\dot q
$$
but
$$
\frac{\partial \dot r}{\partial \dot q}=2\dot q.
$$

Comment: Thank you. It wasn't deep, it was merely a misunderstanding. My book appears to be using very weird notation. Anyway, thank you, again!

Comment: My distant recollection is that multivariable calculus in undergraduate physics was a lot like this. Some of the rules depended on the context to an occasionally confusing degree. I'm sure this all could be expressed in a mathematically precise way, but that (IIRC) would have slowed down the study of physics even more.

Comment: @Valentina Well, the notation isn't all *that* weird. Its purpose is to distinguish between **(1)** $dq/dt$, which suggests the time derivative for a specific solution $q(t)$ to some equations of motion and some starting conditions, and **(2)** $\dot q$, which suggests a parameter to a function that may vary independently of $q$ and $t$, for example in the definition of a Lagrangian.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both $\dot{r}$ and $\dot{q}$ exist and are not zero, your equation follows from the chain rule.
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial q} \cdot \frac{\partial q}{\partial t}
$$

Comment: This answer is in response to the question as it was originally stated.